# NodeJs on Azure - site fails to load

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a very simple expressJs app on Azure, and since March all was working fine...

today I went to the website and I find a "Service Unavailable" as output ... after re-publishing the site, I get a lot of weird errors on the logs that make no sense at all:

log below retrieved from `https://<my app name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream`

```
2018-05-03T23:11:48  Updating branch 'master'.
2018-05-03T23:11:52  Updating submodules.
2018-05-03T23:11:52  Preparing deployment for commit id '7579046ef3'.
2018-05-03T23:11:56  Generating deployment script.
2018-05-03T23:11:56    Using cached version of deployment script (command: 'azure -y --no-dot-deployment -r "/home/site/repository" -o "/home/site/deployments/tools" --node --sitePath "/home/site/repository"').
2018-05-03T23:11:56  Running deployment command...
2018-05-03T23:11:56    Command: "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
2018-05-03T23:11:59    Handling node.js deployment.
2018-05-03T23:11:59    Kudu sync from: '/home/site/repository' to: '/home/site/wwwroot'
2018-05-03T23:11:59    Copying file: '.editorconfig'
2018-05-03T23:11:59    Copying file: '.eslintrc.js'
2018-05-03T23:11:59    Copying file: '.gitignore'
2018-05-03T23:11:59    Copying file: 'Procfile'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: 'bitbucket-pipelines.yml'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: 'package-lock.json'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: 'package.json'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: 'readme.md'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Ignoring: .git
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: '.vscode/launch.json'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: 'public/favicon.ico'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: 'public/swagger.html'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: 'public/swagger.json'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: 'public/swagger.yaml'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: 'server/server.js'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: 'server/models/dtlCall.js'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: 'server/models/dtlError.js'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: 'server/routes/dtl.js'
2018-05-03T23:12:00    Copying file: 'server/routes/index.js'
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Copying file: 'server/utilities/auth.js'
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Copying file: 'server/utilities/error.js'
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Copying file: 'server/utilities/index.js'
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Copying file: 'server/utilities/logger.js'
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Copying file: 'test/common.js'
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Copying file: 'test/mocha.opts'
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Copying file: 'test/config/employees.result.json'
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Copying file: 'test/config/payload.json'
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Copying file: 'test/server/auth.js'
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Copying file: 'test/server/utilities.js'
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Copying file: 'views/default.html'
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Copying file: 'views/default.pug'
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Detecting node version spec...
2018-05-03T23:12:01    Using package.json engines.node value: 8.9.x
2018-05-03T23:12:02    Node.js versions available on the platform are: 4.4.7, 4.5.0, 6.2.2, 6.6.0, 6.9.3, 6.10.3, 6.11.0, 8.0.0, 8.1.0, 8.2.1, 8.8.1, 8.9.4, 9.4.0.
2018-05-03T23:12:02    Resolved to version 8.9.4
2018-05-03T23:12:02    Detecting npm version spec...
2018-05-03T23:12:02    Using package.json engines.npm value: 5.0.x
2018-05-03T23:12:02    NPM versions available on the platform are: 2.15.8, 2.15.9, 3.9.5, 3.10.3, 3.10.10, 5.0.3.
2018-05-03T23:12:02    Resolved to version 5.0.3
2018-05-03T23:12:02    Running "/opt/nodejs/8.9.4/bin/node" "/opt/npm/5.0.3/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" install --production
2018-05-03T23:12:02    npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /usr/bin/node but npm is using /opt/nodejs/8.9.4/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
2018-05-03T23:12:13    npm WARN dtl_api@1.0.0 No repository field.
2018-05-03T23:12:13    removed 5 packages in 10.288s
2018-05-03T23:12:13    
2018-05-03T23:12:13    Finished successfully.
2018-05-03T23:12:13  Running post deployment command(s)...
2018-05-03T23:12:13  Deployment successful.
2018-05-03T23:12:14  App container will begin restart within 10 seconds.

2018-05-03 23:12:57.683 INFO  - Starting container for site
2018-05-03 23:12:57.684 INFO  - docker run -d -p 15062:8080 --name bb-dtl-service__9e0a_0 -e WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=8.9 -e APPSETTING_WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=8.9 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=bb-dtl-service -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=fb29dfd8d91e0378f3794f42c27d2c348a5c5eb0bfc876bcc540f651b3082330 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/node:8.9.4_1804040228 ./server/server.js 

2018-05-03T23:12:59.263038964Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2018-05-03T23:12:59.525171581Z Generating app startup command
2018-05-03T23:12:59.538785224Z Running ./server/server.js
2018-05-03T23:12:59.559830590Z /home/site/wwwroot/server/server.js: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
2018-05-03T23:12:59.559958090Z /home/site/wwwroot/server/server.js: line 1: `const express = require('express');'

2018-05-03 23:13:00.286 ERROR - Container bb-dtl-service__9e0a_0 for site bb-dtl-service__9e0a has exited, failing site start
```

my `server/Server.js` file content is

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// ======================= configuration =================================
const port = process.env.PORT || 4006;
const env = process.env.APP_ENVIRONMENT || 'unknown';

// view engine
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static('public'));

// favicon
app.use(favicon(path.join(`${__dirname}/../`, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));

// use body parser so we can get info from POST and/or URL parameters
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// using morgan to log requests to the console
app.use(morgan(':remote-addr ":referrer" ":user-agent" :method :url :status - :response-time ms'));

// https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-security-checklist/
app.use(helmet());

// ======================= routes ========================================
const apiRoutes = require('./routes');

// API ROUTES ------------------------------------------------------------
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

// OTHER ROUTES ----------------------------------------------------------
app.get('/swagger-ui', (req, res) => {
    // show the swagger definition reader
    // html file from https://github.com/csabapalfi/swagger-ui-min
    res.redirect('/swagger.html');
});
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    // get last commit id and show it on the page
    const lastCommitHash = process.env.SOURCE_VERSION || '';
    const lastCommitShor = lastCommitHash.length > 8 ? lastCommitHash.substr(0, 8) : '';
    res.render('default', { gitHash: lastCommitHash, gitShortHash: lastCommitShor, env });
});

// ======================= start the server ==============================
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Magic happens at http://localhost:${port}`); // eslint-disable-line
});

exports.server = app; // export for testing
```

---

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Why can't the container accept that line?

Why the errors now when all was working fine since March?

I've been trying stuff for 2hours now, and nothing makes any sense :(

---

my application settings

[image]

---

**Updated May 9th**

created a simple `Dockerfile` with:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node

RUN mkdir -p /app
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install && npm update https-proxy-agent --depth 2

CMD npm start
```

as:

```
docker build .
docker run -it -p 8080:4006 -e "MONGODB_URI=mongodb://dbuser:dbpass@dsxxxxxx.mlab.com:19080/mongocollection" 5067e22e341b

> dl_api@1.0.0 start /app
> node ./server/server.js

Magic happens at http://localhost:4006
```

so all works even on docker :/

Comment: Have you ever checked the encoding issue? The common `CRLF` & `LF` problem?

Comment: @JerryLiu should not make any sense on such versions, that was back the day... btw, same commit code runs on Heroku and Locally without any change :o(

Comment: Just a suggestion, as I have found someone met similar issue half a year ago. [container-failing-site-start](https://omgdebugging.com/2017/12/23/azure-web-app-for-container-failing-site-start/)

Comment: @JerryLiu checked all files, all ends with `LF`, created a dockerfile and run the code from docker, though using `mhart/alpine-node` and not Azure specific image... runs fine :(

Comment: Enable `devErrorsEnabled` in your iisnode config, should show you the real problem.

Comment: @James It's a linux machine, I don't have access to xml configurations for IIS ... unless I'm seeing things wrong. Feel free to point me where should I go.

Comment: @balexandre ah that changes things then haha although, I’ve just relooked at your logs and the issue appears to be server.js has an unexpected ` (backtick) character on the first line - are you using any sort of bundler / transpiler that could be modifying your code post deploy?

Comment: @James nothing at all, just plain javascript, my `server.js` is the one I posted in the question. As said, code runs fine from the same commit, in Heroku and Docker :( ... I love Heroku, I love AWS... **I can't fall in love with Azure though** :/ they even have 2 ways of having env variables (through the UI and Kudu API ... and they do not override each other!)

Comment: @balexandre yeah, can be frustrating, I adopted Azure early and been through a lot of teething problems, big problem is Node is really a 2nd class citizen as far as Microsoft are concerned. Have you checked the server.js directly via Kudu? Also have you tried running Node directly from inside the Kudu command line? Presumably you’d get the same error? Would appear *something* is up with your server.js file

Comment: @James running node directly from Kudu is no good as node version is a very old one, the docker image has 8.9. and right there all `const` will stop work :( it's been 11 days and no help from support either :(

Comment: @balexandre yeah the default version will be but you can call the version you want by specifying the full path - just thinking if you do that you’ll figure out if the problem is Node or if it’s infrastructure related